# To check the element of the collection

Tags: android, kotlin, collections

I want to check if my collection already has an item with the same name(`connection.name`) and if there is, then call a method that will do something, for example, change the field: `connection.name`

At the moment I get the collection as follows:

```
override fun getListItems(context: Context): List<ConnectionViewModel> {
return connectionsRepository.getAll().map { connection ->
    ConnectionViewModel(
            code = connection.code,
            name = connection.name,
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want to check if my collection already has an item with the same name(connection.name)

You can do that with `find()` (to get the result) or `any()` (to see if a criterion holds true for at least one element):

```
val found: ConnectionViewModel? = list.find { it.name == expectedName }

val nameExists: Boolean = list.any { it.name == expectedName }
```

---

> and if there is, then call a method that will do something, for example, change the field: connection.name

This should be straightforward given the result of `found` or `nameExists` from above.

```
list.map {
    if (nameExists)
        it.copy(name = differentName)
    else
        it
}
```